# Inserting Data - SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, database

So, I don't completely understand how sql databases and servers work together. Tell me if I'm wrong. Okay, so, I can use Php to insert data into an SQL Database that is set up on the same server that is hosting the website? (Question edited)

Comment: well, PHP is able to insert data to SQL server, but first (a very important step), is to know your server config. do your server installed SQL server & configured properly? do you know the credential of the database? Last, please learn to write PHP first.

Comment: I know PHP, I am not as confident with it as others. I don't have a server but I definitely will get one. But is what I said basically how it works?

Answer (score 2):

If your server is from a third party, they may provide you with a tool such as phpMyAdmin. You can use this tool to create your database and insert information into it. That is, you don't necessarily need a server side language to create and insert data in a database. That said, you will need a server side language or framework to access and manipulate that data in your web applications.

If you are running your own server, you can install phpMYAdmin on it and do the same.

Comment: Thanks. I think I won't use that tool, just to get experience in making it myself, but it's a good option!

Comment: phpmyadmin won't work with SQL server.

Comment: Can I do the same job without the tool? The tool is only meant to make it easier, right? I just want to do it without any tools.

Comment: Raptor is correct. phymyadmin won't work with SQL server.